# Windows 7: PHP 5 Configured with Apache 2.2 when run from Console but not as Service

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2

I'm on Windows 7 and I have installed Apache 2.2, PHP 5 (latest stable build) and MySQL.

I have configured PHP 5 with Apache 2.2 as a module (i.e. LoadModule and AddType statements added in httpd.conf).

Everything seems to work when I start Apache from the console (command prompt) but PHP would not work when the Apache service is started. In this configuration, the localhost/index.php ends up getting downloaded in the browser. Why is that?

My guess is that the Apache Service loads up its own version httpd.conf file. Anybody faced similar problems?

DO note:
 - I know of XAMPP, WAMP etc and I don't want to use them
 - I don't want to use PHP as CGI

Comment: Do you get any error in Apache's `error_log` file ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally switched to XAMPP. But I feel this has to do with some of the default security settings in Windows 7. WinXP gives me no problem.